# How to create a widget from a part of image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, clip

I have an image (blue rect). I want to cut a part of the image by path (red triangle) and create a smaller widget (green rect) that shows this part of the image and has size which equals bounds of cutting path. How can I do it in Flutter?

[image: Example]

I tried to use `ClipPath` and `CustomClipper<Path>`, but I was able to create only widget which has size of the image.

Comment: Please share any working abstracted code for your issue, it's hard to gauge the issue without a baseline.

Comment: Add your code..

Comment: I understand that a code snippet is always good, but the question was about an idea how to write the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ui.Image _uiImage;
  final Path _clipPath;

  const MyWidget({
    Key? key,
    required ui.Image uiImage,
    required Path clipPath,
  })  : _uiImage = uiImage,
        _clipPath = clipPath,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bounds = _clipPath.getBounds();
    
    final translateM = Float64List.fromList([
      1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      -bounds.left, -bounds.top, 0, 1
    ]);
    
    final localClipPath = _clipPath.transform(translateM);
    
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: _MyClipper(localClipPath),
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: _MyPainter(_uiImage, bounds),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: bounds.width,
          height: bounds.height,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final Path _clipPath;

  _MyClipper(this._clipPath);

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => _clipPath;

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}

class _MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image _uiImage;
  final Rect _bounds;

  final _paint = Paint();

  _MyPainter(this._uiImage, this._bounds);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawAtlas(
      _uiImage,
      [
        RSTransform.fromComponents(
          rotation: 0.0,
          scale: 1.0,
          // Center of the sprite relative to its rect
          anchorX: _bounds.width / 2,
          anchorY: _bounds.height / 2,
          // Location at which to draw the center of the sprite
          translateX: _bounds.width / 2,
          translateY: _bounds.height / 2,
        )
      ],
      [_bounds],
      null,
      null,
      null,
      _paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_MyPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are not provide any code, I assume you want to have widget based on current child.

if yes, you may try `IntrinsicWidth` and `IntrinsicHeight` widget.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html

`IntrinsicWidgth`:

> Creates a widget that sizes its child to the child's intrinsic width.
>
> This class is useful, for example, when unlimited width is available
> and you would like a child that would otherwise attempt to expand
> infinitely to instead size itself to a more reasonable width.

With this widget, the child will rendered with based on intrinsic size.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CustomPainter` with [drawAtlas](https://drawAtlas)
, performant, show part of the image. I use this to make animation like sprites Animation

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution without using `CustomClipper`.

**Usage**

```dart
TileWidget(
  uiImage,
  left,  
  top,
  width, 
  height,
);
```

**Code**

```dart
class TileWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int left;
  final int top;
  final int width;
  final int height;
  final ui.Image image;

  const TileWidget(this.image, 
    this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height,
      {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
        size: Size(width.toDouble(), height.toDouble()),
        painter: _SquarePainter(image, left, top, width, height));
  }
}

class _SquarePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final int left;
  final int top;
  final int width;
  final int height;
  final ui.Image tileset;

  _SquarePainter(this.tileset, this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawAtlas(
      tileset,
      [
        RSTransform.fromComponents(
            rotation: 0.0,
            scale: 1.0,
            anchorX: 0.0,
            anchorY: 0.0,
            translateX: 0.0,
            translateY: 0.0)
      ],
      [
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          left.toDouble(),
          top.toDouble(),
          width.toDouble(),
          height.toDouble(),
        )
      ],
      [],
      BlendMode.src,
      null,
      Paint(),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_SquarePainter oldDelegate) => false;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(_SquarePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```